# Building PCL library statically

Tags: cmake, static-libraries, point-cloud-library

I am currently trying to collect data from a camera that only works with static libraries.
Then I have to install PCL statically. Since there is no All-in-one kit as for the dynamic version, I have done it manually, with Cmake. The build succeeded, but even if I set the option in Cmakelists *"set(PCL_SHARED_LIBS OFF) "*, PCL is still built dynamically. I have tried this trick http://www.pcl-users.org/How-to-build-PCL-statically-td4027660.html, but I still have dynamic libraries.

How can I build the static version of PCL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify cached values in the CMake GUI. You should never need to modify the cache file manually. If you don't see the PCL_SHARED_LIBS variable, you might need to check the "Advanced" checkbox.

It's also described [in the PCL documentation](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/compiling_pcl_windows.php):
[image]